# Opening and closing SQLConnections in C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlconnection

can someone tell me how to use a SQL Connection in C# correct?

Right now I am doing it like that:

```
//some Code here
using (var sqlConnection = DatabaseUtil.DatabaseUtil.CreateSqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand();

    DatabaseUtil.DatabaseUtil.InitializeSqlCommand(ref cmd, query, sqlConnection);

    sqlConnection.Open();

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        reader.Read();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            //some code here
        }

        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
    }

    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

`DatabaseUtil` is written in **VB.NET**. Here the Function `CreateSqlConnection`:

```
Public Function CreateSqlConnection(connectionString As String) As SqlConnection
    Dim result As SqlConnection
    result = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Return result
End Function
```

And here you can see the function `InitializeSqlCommand`:

```
Public Sub InitializeSqlCommand(ByRef cmd As SqlCommand, query As String, sqlConnection As SqlConnection)
    cmd.CommandText = query
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection
End Sub
```

Am I doing it *right*? Or do you have some suggestion for *improvement* for me?

I will be appreciative for every tip.

Ali

Comment: Typically, questions asking for improvements to existing working code should go to the Code Review stack exchange site.

Comment: You should call `if (reader.HasRows)` *before* you call `reader.Read();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to start off by saying nothing in the original post is *wrong*, per se, and you could continue to use that code just fine.

But...  we can still do better.

There is no need for the `SqlCommand` argument to `InitializeSqlCommand()` to pass by ref. IMO this is a mistake in the VB code. `ByVal` is good enough here, and `ByRef` exposes your command object to things you might not want.

In the `CreateSqlConnection()` function, I tend to assume if you're creating a connection, you're going to want to open it soon, too. Plus, we can shorten the method some.

I also tend to either put my connection strings directly into my equivalent DatabaseUtil modules, or build the Module so it can load the string from a config file. I don't want to need to pass that data into the `CreateSqlConnection()` method every time. Put these two paragraphs together like this:

```vb
Private ReadOnly Property ConnectionString As String
    Get
         Return "connection string here"
    End Get
End Property

Public Function CreateSqlConnection() As SqlConnection
    Dim result As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    result.Open()
    Return result
End Function
```

It's a small thing, but `SqlCommand` also implements `IDisposble`, so ideally it will also be in a `using` block. Really, there's nothing in the existing `InitializeSqlCommand()` method you can't accomplish directly with the `SqlCommand` constructor, as `CommandType.Text` is already the default. Go ahead and import the `DatabaseUtil` namespace, and you can put these two paragraphs together like this:

```
using (var sqlConnection = DatabaseUtil.CreateSqlConnection())
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
{
```

I also worry about an `InitializeSqlCommand()` command function that accepts a `query` string, but makes no provision for query parameters. Yes, you can still add parameters later in code, but in my experience this tends to encourage the use of string concatenation for parameter data... or more accurately, fails to adequately discourage it, which amounts to the same thing. You want to make sure you don't have SQL Injection vulnerabilities in the application. If you continue to use `InitializeSqlCommand()`, I structure it more like this:

```vb
Public Function InitializeSqlCommand(cn As SqlConnection, query As String, ParamArray paramters() As SqlParamter) As SqlCommand
    Dim result As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
    result.CommandText = query
    If parameters IsNot Nothing AndAlso parameter.Length > 0 Then
       result.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)
    End If
    Return result
End Sub
```

It's not necessary to call `sqlConnection.Close()` if the connection was created in a `using` block. The same applies to the DataReader.

Finally, the typical pattern for the DataReader is **not** to check the `HasRows` property. It's usually enough to *only* check the results of the `Read()` method, and usually in a `while` loop.

Put it all together, including the revised VB functions, like this:

```
var parameters = new SqlParameter[] { }; //define parameters here
using (var sqlConnection = DatabaseUtil.CreateSqlConnection())
using (var cmd = DatabaseUtil.InitializeSqlCommand(sqlConnection, query, parameters))
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

Comment: If in your `CreateSqlConnection` the `.Open` throws, then there is no way to `.Dispose` the connection because the `using`block will never get it. One could argue that an unopened connection is not worth disposing, but that assumes internal knowledge we should not assume.

Comment: All of that is true, including the "one could argue" part.

Comment: If your query is expecting only one row (or none), then `If (reader.Read())...` would make more sense than the while-loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this answer one realy helped me. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt if you want `DatabaseUtil` here; explicit creation with `new` will do:

```
  // If you don't want to hardcode connection's type - SqlConnection -
  // (possible purpose of DatabaseUtil class) use dependency injection
  using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    sqlConnection.Open();

    // sqlConnection.CreateCommand() - we can avoid dependency 
    // and don't hardcode SqlCommand as "new SqlCommand"
    //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using, do not close it explicitly
    using (var cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand()) {
      cmd.CommandText = query;

      //TODO: you may want to provide Parameters here

      //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using, do not close it explicitly
      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        // reader.Read() returns true if record is read 
        // (i.e. we have at least one record)
        if (reader.Read()) {
          // We have at least one row
          // some code here
        } 
      }  
    } 
  }
```

In case you want to read *several records* not just a fact that query returns at least one record, turn `if (reader.Read())` into `while`:

```
      ... 
      //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using, do not close it explicitly
      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        // reader.Read() returns true if record is read 
        while (reader.Read()) {
          // record has been read
          // some code here 
        } 
      }  
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the `DatabaseUtil`. just do it like this:

```
using (var sqlConnection =new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
   var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
   sqlConnection.Open();
   var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while(reader.Read())
    {
         //do whatever you want
    };
}
```

You don't need to close the connection, when you use `using`.